# Query for string containing one or more of many strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I found an example here:

```
var foo = things.Where(data => myList.Contains(data.Title));
```

However this is exact string matching. I am only interested in it if data.Title.ToLower() contains any of the strings found in list ToLower().

Say list has apple, book ClocK in it.

data.Title is for example: Apple Jacks, Book Club, Clockwork Book, those are all fine. But Claws and Foods, Clicks, Application Fundamentals, would not be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to look for each item that the `Title` may contain (ignoring case):

```
var foo = things.Where(data => myList
                .Any(item => data.Title.ToLower().Contains(item.ToLower())));
```

Comment: If Title tolower contains 1 or more item tolower, keep it, else, discard.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myList = new List<string> { "apple", "book", "ClocK" };
var things = new List<string> { "Apple Jacks", "Book Club", "Clockwork Book", "Claws and Foods", "Clicks", "Application Fundamentals" };
var myRegex = new Regex(string.Join("|", myList.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (var matchingThing in things.Where(x => myRegex.IsMatch(x)))
    Console.WriteLine(matchingThing);
```

Outputs:

```
Apple Jacks
Book Club
Clockwork Book
```

Comment: While this is cool, I find Gert's answer easier to understand at a glance.